# Executing functions in a sequence

Tags: python

Let's say I have three functions, a, b, and c. I want to execute them in order with a specific parameter, and print a value related to their execution. Something like:

```
funcDict = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: "c"
}

for func in funcDict:
    func("test")
    print(funcDict(func))
```

Comment: What python version do you have?

Comment: 3.5, but I was wondering in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have better options with list, mostly for the order :

```
func_list= [
    (a, "a"),
    (b, "b"),
    (c, "c")
]

for func, param in func_list:
    func("test")
    print(func(param))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running on *python3.6*, dictionaries are ordered, so this indeed works:

```
for func in funcDict:
    func("test")
    print(func(funcDict[func]))
```

On older python versions, I would recommend a list of lists or list of tuples, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498427/4909087) recommends.